# Multiple lines colored according to a variable other than the line group

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I have a data frame like the following that I want to plot in `ggplot2`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
x <- seq(N)
d <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 1*x + 1,
    group1 = "1",
    group2 = 1
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 1*x + 2,
    group1 = "2",
    group2 = 1
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 2*x + 1,
    group1 = "3",
    group2 = 2
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 2*x + 2,
    group1 = "4",
    group2 = 2
  )
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = group1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

However, I want to color the lines according to the `group2` variable instead of the `group1` variable. That is, I want the four lines to be distinct lines, but I want to color them according to variable other than that `group1` variable that defines the four lines. I also want the legend to correspond to the `group2` variable.

What would be the syntax to implement this?

Comment: `aes(x, y, group = group1, color = group2)`?

Comment: @Axeman I'm embarrassed that I've used `ggplot2` for years and either never knew that or used to and then forgot it. Want a quick +25? That 100% solved my issue.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but don't have time to go search right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, given in a comment by [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman), is to use a separate `group` and `col` in the `aes`, so `aes(x, y, group = group1, color = group2)`. The entire syntax and plot are below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
x <- seq(N)
d <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 1*x + 1,
    group1 = "1",
    group2 = 1
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 1*x + 2,
    group1 = "2",
    group2 = 1
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 2*x + 1,
    group1 = "3",
    group2 = 2
  ),
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    y = 2*x + 2,
    group1 = "4",
    group2 = 2
  )
)
d$group2 <- as.factor(d$group2) # I happen to want `group2` to 
                                # be a factor, but this is not strictly necessary
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group = group1, color = group2)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]